# NHibernate Mapping Problem - Can I Map Multiple Assemblies?

Tags: nhibernate, orm, nhibernate-mapping

I have the following mapping file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
assembly="Project1.Accounts"
namespace="Project1.Core.Domain">
    <class name="Equipment" table="Equipment">
        <id name="ID" column="ID">
            <generator class="identity"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="Name" />
        <property name="Description" />
        <property name="AccountID" />
        <property name="EquipmentTypeID" />
        <many-to-one name="Account" class="Project2.Core.Domain.Account, Project2.Core" column="AccountID"/>
        <many-to-one name="EquipmentType" class="Insight.IT.Accounts.Core.Domain.EquipmentType, Insight.IT.Accounts" column="EquipmentTypeID"/>
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

I'm getting the following error:

NHibernate.MappingException: An association from the table Equipment refers to an unmapped class: Project2.Domain.Account

Just to be clear - The Account class lives in a different assembly than the Equipment class does. The project that the Account class resides in has it's own hibernate.cfg.xml.

Basically, it looks like i need a way to reference multiple mapping assemblies in the hibernate.cfg.xml file.  Is this possible??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the responses.  Actually, I ended up doing it a little different.  I just removed the  tag from the hibernate.cfg and used fully qualified names in the .hbm.xml files.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
        <property name="dialect">...</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">...</property>
        ...
        <mapping assembly="MyProject.OtherAssembly"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Yep, this'll do it.  It doesn't have to be in one assembly as you can have multiple `<mapping assembly />` tags.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, you'll just have to indicate this in your mapping file (and it looks like you did this).

Did you add both the assemblies to the NHibernate configuration, before creating the sessionfactory ?